# Create one data frame out of different list columns

Tags: r, list, purrr

I've imported a `json` file into R. Now I have one character column with unique identifiers `dbc` followed by multiple list columns `lookup.company.year` which contain data frames. What I want to do is to make a one big tibble (data frame). I prefer solutions with the `purrr` package.

This is just a very small piece of my data:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  dbc       lookup.CZ.2016       lookup.CZ.2017       lookup.DSW.2016      lookup.DSW.2017     
  <chr>     <list>               <list>               <list>               <list>              
1 019999006 <data.frame [1 × 2]> <data.frame [1 × 2]> <data.frame [1 × 2]> <data.frame [1 × 2]>
```

With the a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(dbc = "019999006", lookup.CZ.2016 = list(structure(list(
    name = "MC Groep (Zuiderzee Lelystad, Emmeloord, Dronten)", 
    price = 18575.66), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
    lookup.CZ.2017 = list(structure(list(name = "Albert Schweitzer Ziekenhuis", 
        price = 23024.57), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
    lookup.DSW.2016 = list(structure(list(name = "MC Groep (Zuiderzee Lelystad, Emmeloord, Dronten)", 
        price = 21991L), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
    lookup.DSW.2017 = list(structure(list(name = "Albert Schweitzer Ziekenhuis", 
        price = 23603.59), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
    lookup.Menzis.2018 = list(NULL)), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And the desired outcome:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  dbc      company year name                                            price
     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>                                              <dbl>
1 19999006 CZ     2016 MC Groep (Zuiderzee Lelystad, Emmeloord, Dronten) 18576.
2 19999006 CZ     2017 Albert Schweitzer Ziekenhuis                      23025.
3 19999006 DSW    2016 MC Groep (Zuiderzee Lelystad, Emmeloord, Dronten) 21991 
4 19999006 DSW    2017 Albert Schweitzer Ziekenhuis                      23604.
```

I also have `NULL` values. I want to exclude those, that's why I included one in the example dataset.

**Update**

How can I exclude empty `list()` from dataset so other than `NULL`?

[image]

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way via `tidyverse` (did not need `purrr`),

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 gather(var, val, -dbc) %>% 
 group_by(grp = sub('^.*\\.(.*)\\..*', '\\1', var)) %>% 
 filter(val != 'NULL') %>% 
 unnest()
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 4 x 5
> # Groups:   grp [2]
>   dbc       var             grp   name                                               price
>   <chr>     <chr>           <chr> <chr>                                              <dbl>
> 1 019999006 lookup.CZ.2016  CZ    MC Groep (Zuiderzee Lelystad, Emmeloord, Dronten) 18576.
> 2 019999006 lookup.CZ.2017  CZ    Albert Schweitzer Ziekenhuis                      23025.
> 3 019999006 lookup.DSW.2016 DSW   MC Groep (Zuiderzee Lelystad, Emmeloord, Dronten) 21991 
> 4 019999006 lookup.DSW.2017 DSW   Albert Schweitzer Ziekenhuis                      23604.
> ```

Comment: doesn't tidyverse also load `purrr`?

Comment: @mtoto yes it does. Along with all of Hadley's packages. I just didn't use any of its functions

Comment: When running my original datset it runs this error: `Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [val]` Is this perhaps because besides having list vectors and `NULL` values I have `list()` values. How do I exclude those?

Comment: So you have nested lists? That is probably it. Can you exclude them manually? Are they a lot?

Comment: I don't see a non-consistency except for the empty `list()` is that it?

Comment: Probably. You can filter them out using `lengths`, i.e. `...filter(lengths(val) >= 1)`